# How to use jQuery insted of Update panel?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to use the jQuery ajax instead of update panel in Asp.net? I've heard it's lighter that the normal update panel. Also, does it need a script manager?

Comment: What exactly you want to use for( It is lighter than Updatepanel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, There will be less overhead on network if you use jQuery instead of UpdatePanel..
however you need to write lot of js code for handling data returned by `GET` and `POST` requests using jquery `$.ajax()` function.
On the other side asp.net ajax will handle DOM updates etc. automatically

check this tutorial
[JQuery: Building tomorrow's Web apps today](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-jquery3/)